# Centos PHP upgrade failure

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, php

I needed to upgrade from PHP 5.x to 7

removed old components using yum - remove php*
Installed remi repo, updated all
Install seemed to work however Its faulting with an m-crypt problem and Im not sure how to repair it? Output below

```
# yum install php-mcrypt

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, replace
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.intergrid.com.au
 * epel: fedora.uberglobalmirror.com
 * extras: mirror.intergrid.com.au
 * ius: ius.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au
 * remi-safe: remi.conetix.com.au
 * updates: mirror.intergrid.com.au
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.4.16-7.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64 for package: php-mcrypt-5.4.16-7.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20100412-64 for package: php-mcrypt-5.4.16-7.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.4.16-42.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php70u-common-7.0.19-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 7.0.19
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php70u-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 3 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
ipa-client-4.4.0-14.el7.centos.7.x86_64 has installed conflicts freeipa-client: ipa-client-4.4.0-14.el7.centos.7.x86_64
ipa-client-common-4.4.0-14.el7.centos.7.noarch has installed conflicts freeipa-client-common: ipa-client-common-4.4.0-14.el7.centos.7.noarch
ipa-common-4.4.0-14.el7.centos.7.noarch has installed conflicts freeipa-common: ipa-common-4.4.0-14.el7.centos.7.noarch

# rpm -qa | grep php

php70-php-cli-7.0.20-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php70-php-pecl-memcache-3.0.9-0.7.20161124gitdf7735e.el7.remi.x86_64
php70-php-process-7.0.20-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php70-php-pecl-zip-1.14.0-1.el7.remi.x86_64
mod_php70u-7.0.19-1.ius.centos7.x86_64
php70-php-pecl-geoip-1.1.1-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php70-php-json-7.0.20-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php70-php-mcrypt-7.0.20-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php70-runtime-1.0-5.el7.remi.x86_64
php70-php-opcache-7.0.20-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php70u-common-7.0.19-1.ius.centos7.x86_64
php70-php-xml-7.0.20-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php70-php-pecl-xmldiff-1.1.2-6.el7.remi.x86_64
php70-php-tidy-7.0.20-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php70-php-common-7.0.20-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php70-php-xmlrpc-7.0.20-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php70-php-pecl-json-post-1.0.1-3.el7.remi.x86_64
php70u-mysqlnd-7.0.19-1.ius.centos7.x86_64
php70-php-pecl-apcu-bc-1.0.3-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php70-php-pspell-7.0.20-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php70-php-gd-7.0.20-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php70u-pdo-7.0.19-1.ius.centos7.x86_64
php70-php-mbstring-7.0.20-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php70u-cli-7.0.19-1.ius.centos7.x86_64
php70-php-soap-7.0.20-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php70-php-pecl-apcu-5.1.8-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php70-php-pecl-imagick-3.4.3-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php70-php-devel-7.0.20-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php70-php-pear-1.10.4-2.el7.remi.noarch
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? How would I go about "nuking" it and starting over? Or is more information needed to solve

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have parts of PHP7 from IUS repo in your installation. Remove everything with the name `php70u` before trying to install PHP from Remi's repo.

Additional, you appear to have some conflicts in the IPA client libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 PHP stacks installed, which seems obviously not needed.

- php70u-* from IUS
- php70-php-* from Remi

For Remi's repository usage, I recommend you simply follow the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) instructions.

So, in your case, you need php70-php-mcrypt from remi (or php70u-mcrpypt in IUS case, or php-mycrypt if you choose "single version" from "remi-php70")

BTW, about mcrypt extension, I recommend you to read : [About libmcrypt and php-mcrypt](https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2015/07/07/About-libmcrypt-and-php-mcrypt)